# Image tag with background image has a border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an HTML button that shows an icon on top of some text:

```
<button class="btn btn-link center">

    <img class="connect">
    <br/>
    CONNECT

</button>
```

My image states are defined in CSS:

```
.connect{
    background-image:url('../images/connect_rest.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
} 

.connect:hover{
    background-image:url('../images/connect_hover.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
}

.connect:active{
    background-image:url('../images/connect_active.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
}
```

So, why is there a white border around my box? I get it, I know it's funky that I'm setting a background-image on an image element. But, I need this compatible with IE8 so I can't set the "content" property in CSS.

Thanks for any helpful tips.

Comment: Img tag without src is wrong!
use a span and set background image.

Comment: As mentioned, using img tags as such is really poor coding practice. But if you're insistent are you sure the border isn't coming from the <button>

Comment: Going with @Sumit approach. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default any img without the src attribute set will be styled with a grey border.

That's why there is no way to remove that border because it's a browser default.

If you have to use an element inside a button **DO NOT USE** an img without src.

Also in general using it without setting `width:0;` and `height:0;` is not a good idea.

I built a quick demo for you to show you the difference between elements inside a button:

- Using an `img` with no `src` attribute set or empty.
- `img` with src
- `span`

**DEMO**

```css
.img-no-src, .span{
    background-image:url('http://placehold.it/200x200');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;    
    border: none;
    -webkit-appearance:none; 
     margin:10px auto; 
} 

.img-no-src:hover{
    background-image:url('http://placehold.it/200x200/020/029');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;  
}

.img-no-src:active{
    background-image:url('http://placehold.it/200x200/020/029');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
}
.only-img{
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    display:block;
    margin:10px auto; 
    
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-link center">
    <img class="only-img" src="http://placehold.it/200x200/" />
    with img with src
    <img class="img-no-src"  />
    with img with no src
    <span class="span"></span>
    with span
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation; really appreciate that.

Answer (score -2):

Try putting background:none; on your .connect class.
Instead of using button though, why not use span or div since you are basically taking away all of the button features anyway?

Comment: I wanted to use a button because I can easily apply a disabled class to it without custom CSS that I'd have to use on a DIV or SPAN to make it look disabled.